# Scope of a delegate in C#

Tags: c#, scope, delegates

Can delegates be private? If not, what's the reason behind this other than the normal restrictions caused by it being private?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Delegates have the same restrictions as any type with regards to visibility.  So you **cannot have a private delegate at the top level**.

```
namespace Test
{
    private delegate void Impossible();
}
```

This generates a compiler error:

> Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal

But like a class, **you can declare a delegate private when it resides within another class**.

```
namespace Test
{
    class Sample
    {
        // This works just fine.
        private delegate void MyMethod();

        // ...
    }
}
```

The reason basically goes back to the definition of [what `private` is in C#:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2(VS.80).aspx)

> **private**  |  Access is limited to the containing type.

Comment: nice, thanks bobbymcr. sometimes, we need a reinforcement of concepts/basics.